# How can I get a checkbox to return True/False?

Tags: 7, forms

I'm working with the form API and I have a series of checkboxes. I need them to return `true` or `false` instead of `1` and `0`.

```
$form['checkbox1'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#return_value' => 'true',
    '#title' => t('Checkbox title'),
    );
```

This works if the box is checked, but if it's left unchecked it still returns `0`. Is there a way I can get an unchecked box to return `false`?

Comment: Is there any reason you want to get `FALSE` instead of `0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends how you want to use the true/false value.

**Case 1**

You could change the data in a validation handler. In hook_form_alter, something like:

```
$form['#validate'][] = 'my_great_handler';
```

Then:

```
function my_great_handler($form, &form_state){
  $form_state['values']['checkbox1'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] 
    = ($form_state['values']['checkbox1'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] == 1);
}
```

Not sure what that would do for you, though.

**Case 2**

If you want to show users true/false rather than 1 or 0, you could change that in a template. Create a template for the field, and add something like:

```
Checkbox: <?php print $checkbox1 == 1 ? 'True' : 'False'; ?>
```

**Case 3**

If you want to save the data in a custom data store, you would add similar code right before the save, in hook_node_save, or some such.